# 4 sample classes _ tumor and normal paired sample

Tags: generalized-linear-model, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have 4 sample classes - normal and tumor always from the same patient. So I have Long_survival Normal and Tumor, and Short_survivals Normal and Tumor.
Since there is dependency of data, Norma and Tumor are paired, what test I should use.Data are not normally distributed.So my initial analysis Tumor versus Normal was Wilcox test.

To do pairwise comparison would be wrong? How to compare Short Tumor versus Long Tumor? Since I have age sex confounders can I use GLM?

Thanks you

Comment: The description of your experimental design is unclear. Can you explain how you can have 4 sample classes all with the same patient? How many patients? Perhaps, take one patient as an example and describe exactly what data you have for that patient. // One possible interpretation of what you say prompts me to suggest you look at a Friedman test, which generalizes a paired Wilcoxon test to handle 'blocks'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry to be unclear.  I have 24 samples (from 12 patients, each patient has pair of normal and tumor biopsy).  So, I have 12 samples of Long  and 12 of Short survivals. Each group of 12 have - 6 tumor and 6 normal samples - which are pairs per each individual .  If I use Wilcox test it means that I always consider pairwise comparison? Tumor vs Normal (long), Tumor vs Normal (short), Short versus Long (tumor, these are not pairs), and Short versus Long Normal (these are not pairs).

Comment: I also have to correct for confounders-age, gender,  in comparsong Long ve Short (since these are not from the same patients).....